# Creating a formula which references a Variable in WEBI Business Objects

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I am using a formula to successfully convert a number of minutes into "HH:mm" format-

```
=ToDate(If((IsNull([Totalmins])) Or([Totalmins] = 0 )) Then ("00:00") Else FormatNumber(Floor([Totalmins] /60) ;"00") + ":" + FormatNumber(Floor(Mod([Totalmins] ;60)/1) ;"00");"HH:mm")
```

This works fine where Totalmins is an absolute number.  However I also want to convert the SUM of the Totalmins column into HH:mm format, but I can't get it to work.
I have tried creating a variable called TotalMinSum which is "=Sum([Totalmins])", and referenced it from the same formula-

```
=ToDate(If((IsNull([TotalMinSum])) Or([TotalMinSum] = 0 )) Then ("00:00") Else FormatNumber(Floor([TotalMinSum] /60) ;"00") + ":" + FormatNumber(Floor(Mod([TotalMinSum] ;60)/1) ;"00");"HH:mm")
```

...but this does not work.  It just gives me an #ERROR.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself.  Went into Designer and added a variable into the universe with the value of sum(@Select(ProjectTotals\Totalmins)).  I am now able to use this in the report as if it is an absolute value.